# Android : mark as checked a check box

Tags: java, android, checkbox

In my android app, I want to define a check box which should be marked as checked. Can anyone plz explain how to do it ?

Thanx in advance

Comment: checkBox.setChecked(true);

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the xml file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define in xml like the following:

```
<CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your text"
        android:checked="true"
        />
```

If you want to attain the same in java, you can use `setChecked(boolean)` attribute of `checkbox`.

Like,

```
checkbox.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setChecked(boolean)` method. It is a method from CompoundButtons, which CheckBox extends. See docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

public void setSelected (boolean selected)

Answer (score 0):

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkIos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chk_ios" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkAndroid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chk_android"
        android:checked="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkWindows"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chk_windows" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_display" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Make CheckBox is checked by default :
Put android:checked="true" inside checkbox element to make it checked bu default. In this case, **“Android”** option is checked by default.